Link to library's PDB file using CMake
I have a problem. I use a library which is linked statically, and I have the .pdb file for debug info which corresponds to that library. However, I am not sure how to "link" to that .pdb file.
Note: both library (.lib) and .pdb files are prebuilt, meaning that I just downloaded them. Also {ENGINE_TARGET} is a target which gets compiled to .lib as well.
This is how I link to the library (see comments in code):
target_include_directories(${ENGINE_TARGET} 
    PUBLIC 
        "src/"
        "vendor/imgui"
        "vendor/ImGuizmo"
        "vendor/taskflow"
        "vendor/glm"
    PRIVATE 
        "${Vulkan_SDK}\\Include" 
        "${Vulkan_SDK}\\Source" 
        ${Stb_INCLUDE_DIR}
        "vendor/Jolt"
        "vendor/mono/include/mono-2.0"
        "vendor/bc7enc_rdo/include"
        "vendor/nv-libdeflate"
        "vendor/meshoptimizer/src"
        "vendor/fastgltf/include"
        "vendor/NVAftermath/include"
        "vendor/miniball/cpp/main"
        "vendor/METIS" // <--- HERE is that library's location
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${ENGINE_TARGET}
    PRIVATE 
        debug shaderc_sharedd.lib optimized shaderc_shared.lib
        debug shaderc_utild.lib optimized shaderc_util.lib
        glfw
        Jolt
        libmono-static-sgen.lib
        MonoPosixHelper.lib
        Ws2_32.lib
        Winmm.lib
        Version.lib
        Bcrypt.lib
        bc7enc_rdo
        OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX
        nv_libdeflate
        meshoptimizer
        fastgltf
        metis.lib // <--- HERE is the library itself. I want to also link to `metis.pdb`
        GKlib.lib
)


you don't link to pdb files, its loaded by your debugger and is not related to cmake

@AlanBirtles Oh, so I just put it in the working directory and it will work?...

Depends on your debugger
